# Python: Custom Exception Class deriving from ValueError

Tags: python

My question seems rather simply, but I didn't find any post to this particular issue. I need my own custom exception class deriving from ValueError to print the expected type (standard error msg) as well as the type that was entered (with custom text).

```
class MyOwnException(ValueError):
  ...

try:
    raise MyOwnException ( int('str') ) #not sure what to do here, as I only want to
                                        #raise the exception if incorrect value type
except MyOwnException as e:
        print "Error: Expected type", e.expType() #int
        print "Error: Entered type", e.entType()  #string
```

To add to the above and raising my custom exception via the built-in ValueError:

```
class MyOwnException(ValueError):
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
  print "Error: Expected type", type(self.value) #int
  print "Error type", self.value #how to return expected value type?

try:
    int('str')               
except ValueError as e:
    raise MyOwnException(e)
```

I would very much appreatiate any help in this regard. Thanks very much!
Cheers, Manuel

Comment: Who's going to raise the Error? Your example won't work, because int is a builtin-class and doesn't know about your custom exceptions. Exception don't happen automagically, every exception is raised "manually" because of a conscious decision.

Comment: This wouldn't even help. `int` can take a string just fine. There's no "expected" type because python is not a static language. `int('5')` is just fine

Answer (score 5):

It's generally the case that when raising custom exceptions, you have to catch a more generic exception and re-raise a different one. So for example,

```
>>> class MoofiError(ValueError):
...     pass
... 
>>> try:
...     int('a')
... except ValueError:
...     raise MoofiError, 'you did something wrong, fool'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
__main__.MoofiError: you did something wrong, fool
```

Comment: Thanks very much! However, how can you only display your custom error message, meaning ingoring the `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
__main__.MoofiError: you did something wrong, fool` Thanks!

Comment: @user1233923, if you want to raise an _exception_, there's no easy way. There might be some kind of ugly hack, but it's not worth it. Why are you raising this exception? Are you trying to deal with _user_ error here? Or _programmer_ error? If you're dealing with programmer error, you don't want to quash the traceback. If you're dealing with user error, I don't think you want to use an exception at all.

Answer (score 1):

The `int` function will always return a ValueError, rather than your custom type.

In order to throw a different exception, you would have to wrap `int` to catch ValueError and then raise an exception of your choice (which could include the failing value, as you want).

Answer (score 1):

This code creates a new exception class

```
class MyOwnException(ValueError): pass
```

However nothing will make someone else's code raise your exception - you can only raise it in yours.

Comment: basic question : how does it help to sub class an exception. Does it change the namespace ... or signature .... ?

Comment: @nish How are you going to catch a specific exception type if you don't create a specific exception type?